# must be a valid JSON string Laravel and Postman

Tags: php, laravel, postman

I'm trying to pass a simple array of JSON objects to Laravel and my validator is failing. I'm not sure if this is a problem regarding `Postman` or `Laravel` validator itself.

Passing data from Postman:

```
semester:1
academic_year:2
civil_year:2016
course_id:1
periods[0]:{ "id": 2, "starts": '2018-01-01', "end": '2018-06-01' }
```

[image: passing data via postman]

Laravel Validator:

```
Validator::validate($request->all(), [
            'semester'      => 'integer|between:1,2',
            'academic_year' => 'required|integer|between:1,4',
            'civil_year'    => 'required|integer|between:' . date('Y', strtotime('-5 years')) . ',' . date('Y', strtotime('+5 years')),
            'course_id'     => 'required|integer|exists:courses,id',
            'periods'       => 'required|array|between:1,4',
            'periods.*'     => 'required|json'
        ]);
```

The validator is returning:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "periods.0": [
            "The periods.0 must be a valid JSON string."
        ]
    }
}
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried passing as `raw` the request from `Postman` but without any luck:

[image: passing data as raw]

Also, I have tried inserting the headers

```
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
```

Comment: that feeling you feel when you google your question and you come back to it months later :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested using postman, and the validation fails if I use single quotes like you had here:

```
{ "id": 2, "starts": '2018-01-01', "end": '2018-06-01'}
```

Try using double quotes like this:

```
{ "id": 2, "starts": "2018-01-01", "end": "2018-06-01"}
```

It should pass.

Answer (score 0):

I just added two strings

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
```

and it's working nice.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I got this error because I placed my string variable wrongly in my postman.

Like this:

```json
{
  "Name": sola"
}
```

Instead of:

```json
{
  "Name": "sola"
}
```